# What word/phrase captures this ‘reverberation’ effect?

Tags: single-word-requests

Consider the following scenario if you were at a music concert:

- A singer sings into a microphone
- The sound comes out from the speakers
- The sound from the speaker is picked up by the microphone
- The sound comes out from the speakers
- The sound from the speaker is picked up by the microphone
- ...

This kind of loop can manifest itself in other ways. E.g. happiness breeds success, success breeds happiness which breeds success, and so on.

What’s the best word/phrase that captures this phenomenon?

Comment: Yep, it's "feedback", often with an off-color adjective attached.

Comment: And it should be noted that "feedback" is often used in other contexts, sometimes as an allusion to the audio effect, sometimes not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first case is specifically referred to as Audio Feedback or Acoustic Feedback or even simply feedback

As for the general case you mentioned, it could be called a self-perpetuating cycle.

The terms vicious/virtuous cycle are also used depending on the favorability of the repeating outcomes

Answer (score 0):

I think "loop" does the job, but when I think of it only **perpetual feedback** comes to me